# In matplotlib, how to write different font type and font size in xlabel

Tags: python, fonts, matplotlib, label, axes

I want to write an ion name in one of the labels in a plot, and I need to change the font type and size in just two characters in a line, e.g.;

[CII] => Here II should use a smaller font and possibly a different font e.g., Helvetica, while the other fonts can be stay as Times New Roman.

I would be happy if someone show me a way to do it.

Thanks

Comment: @paul-h This gives a different font but not exactly what I want. \mathrm{[C}\mathtt{II}\mathrm{]}

Comment: you need to put that into a minimal working example. see www.sscce.org for more info about that.